# Very simple grpc/proto endpoint implementation causing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl

Tags: kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, micronaut

The closest issue I found is [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37435) and basically it says: "... you use the version of kotlin-stdlib on the runtime classpath not lower than the one on the compile classpath... "

As far as I can see I am right with kotlin versions.

My whole project is quite small and can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/demo-money)

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.13"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.tolearn"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.tolearn.*")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0:jdk7@jar")
    api("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.0.0")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.tolearn.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }


}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc")
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/java")
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.34.1" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0:jdk7@jar" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
micronautVersion=2.2.2
kotlinVersion=1.4.10
```

Full logs when I try to debug the application inside of IntelliJ

```
C:\JDKs\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57835:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\_d\toLearn\demo-money\build\classes\java\main;C:\_d\toLearn\demo-money\build\classes\kotlin\main;C:\_d\toLearn\demo-money\build\tmp\kapt3\classes\main;C:\_d\toLearn\demo-money\build\resources\main;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-kotlin-stub\1.0.0\a9b64135291f02726f437bf82822142dea3d963d\grpc-kotlin-stub-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin\1.0.0\d6c8cbe29c60b202165593be5244ce43d37378ac\protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-jdk7.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-validation\2.2.2\4c9978ae69745ab3c5afd37d3c2e6c7f5a59190b\micronaut-validation-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.4.10\998caa30623f73223194a8b657abd2baec4880ea\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.4.10\e2b3c6695eee6085e606d96d685396dce23a3a06\kotlin-reflect-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut.kotlin\micronaut-kotlin-runtime\2.2.0\b8b24a7e5ea4d68afd6edc283f2b1f944bbf2cc7\micronaut-kotlin-runtime-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-client\2.2.2\740a9b3ee54d66b838675e62df3c9bbdd8f1028b\micronaut-http-client-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut.grpc\micronaut-grpc-runtime\2.2.0\1ed2e5c0f592d2f92eab105f60293f0c1cab6e92\micronaut-grpc-runtime-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-runtime\2.2.2\ffee1b2088cd3bd699646940dc37ccc537d6f77\micronaut-runtime-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-inject\2.2.2\dbbd8cf931e3714ef0e9ce635a1023a383785c25\micronaut-inject-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-protobuf\1.33.1\4999a8c87e4264be11749b0e3c82526fb7481daf\grpc-protobuf-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-stub\1.33.1\cf2c3b997646a3f065efbaa72528dc7c67e80d77\grpc-stub-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http\2.2.2\3e8dbd9635f2ae40acf95dfeecf424cc46d759a0\micronaut-http-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\77100a62c2e6f04b53977b9f541044d7d722693d\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.4.10\30e46450b0bb3dbf43898d2f461be4a942784780\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.4.10\ea29e063d2bbe695be13e9d044dcfb0c7add398e\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-client-core\2.2.2\b939e521a859d2f691f352d2d274693d2e979039\micronaut-http-client-core-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-netty\2.2.2\d95de1cfb8f14ebe7c025ed1d994734bdc97aa76\micronaut-http-netty-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-websocket\2.2.2\6b9727c73e352f3c2b8ad86f74f172de465c5035\micronaut-websocket-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.56.Final\3acd2ead521786303faf2f85308b98ba174c53b6\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut.grpc\micronaut-grpc-client-runtime\2.2.0\89ebc47606ca77e186a3e182ac5eccd0cfce193e\micronaut-grpc-client-runtime-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut.grpc\micronaut-grpc-server-runtime\2.2.0\f4e9472b6124f5e7db1ce229c7a1059db6589b84\micronaut-grpc-server-runtime-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-aop\2.2.2\1389d1a032d2d6599c132e3f1daab239724e691d\micronaut-aop-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex.rxjava2\rxjava\2.2.10\18e9edc67e0abaa03713eeb9ca2cb0e30c859de4\rxjava-2.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.11.2\d4c1933a8d62db65c3d5a5cd809511e021a189c0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.11.2\e6235e5eb3cf3edd2a95cd0dc96bc48aeb309e8a\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-core\2.2.2\c85844828723dcd0ccbf9fa70cb406d6c49d083b\micronaut-core-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.26\a78a8747147d2c5807683e76ec2b633e95c14fe9\snakeyaml-1.26.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-protobuf-lite\1.33.1\1972b32eca6661ac99f0d0d1f6bc78836a0aaa98\grpc-protobuf-lite-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-api\1.33.1\110c50b7376a5083392a35cace95fbe121fefbc3\grpc-api-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\3.14.0\bb6430f70647fc349fffd1690ddb889dc3ea6699\protobuf-java-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.api.grpc\proto-google-common-protos\1.17.0\40471bf2045151c17da555889b5550fcfd5224a8\proto-google-common-protos-1.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\29.0-android\a51b7d9cbfcce79a88c961907c1767c6de201f31\guava-29.0-android.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.3.4\dac170e4594de319655ffb62f41cbd6dbb5e601e\error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.4.10\6229be3465805c99db1142ad75e6c6ddeac0b04c\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-buffer-netty\2.2.2\fec1f3c421efbffaefa261e85d0f967b5157cd52\micronaut-buffer-netty-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http2\4.1.56.Final\124a9dc7d71e1d8df8cddf588f52f3a353ed30c6\netty-codec-http2-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.56.Final\b67fa83d89476f66de30fa0808cf2fd019a43a06\netty-codec-http-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler\4.1.56.Final\6a3ccbc2c9d0b462643a1904ae6cdb84169546\netty-handler-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.56.Final\6bda6496c20c477d475e63934571eebdd07560e1\netty-codec-socks-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec\4.1.56.Final\2d828cca651f2a37de5735f0d79cbe77228c9d21\netty-codec-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-transport\4.1.56.Final\8809fc38a761463f2f43032918e9d455a622f6be\netty-transport-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-buffer\4.1.56.Final\92466b8de0e325a906c53bbaa9585091ef22001d\netty-buffer-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-common\4.1.56.Final\8e4888cfc66b7ec5a9fb291d9593511481274089\netty-common-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut.grpc\micronaut-grpc-annotation\2.2.0\cecd044579bcbb555bea1f74becc172df8131fd1\micronaut-grpc-annotation-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\d9fb7a7926ffa635b3dcaa5049fb2bfa25b3e7d0\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.spotbugs\spotbugs-annotations\4.0.3\755cc5d84d32b31beeaf8597181f0fc4eac98e16\spotbugs-annotations-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-context\1.33.1\5d312ce1acad9869f118f01cef70a1d5ae7657a8\grpc-context-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\1dcf1de382a0bf95a3d8b0849546c88bac1292c9\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\b421526c5f297295adef1c886e5246c39d4ac629\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.5.5\435dc33e3019c9f019e15f01aa111de9d6b2b79c\checker-compat-qual-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\ba035118bc8bac37d7eff77700720999acd9986d\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-resolver\4.1.56.Final\548076140d58591265533418529e28c7ebbf8422\netty-resolver-4.1.56.Final.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-kotlin\2.11.3\ad8d29545c5ab0cdd6d49ee38f7ece8d9f772815\jackson-module-kotlin-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlinx\kotlinx-coroutines-core\1.3.3\5bac48cf5828e9b006f3b1ef6e37d2a70c2e7321\kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.typesafe\config\1.4.1\19058a07624a87f90d129af7cd9c68bee94535a9\config-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.11.3\4f7b27416934dc929bb6c2d2c5fe521829e6a4ec\jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.11.3\25d4e9c777e7a8805c4a000a8629d3009c779c9b\jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.18\f7aa683ea79dc6681ee9fb95756c999acbb62f5d\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.18.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-netty\1.33.1\db8c0e98533e5b57264dac2ef827661724f2575f\grpc-netty-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.11.3\c2351800432bdbdd8284c3f5a7f0782a352aa84a\jackson-core-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.grpc\grpc-core\1.33.1\55343c9703cd8a44cc2978b117b0a964d470e263\grpc-core-1.33.1.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.perfmark\perfmark-api\0.19.0\2bfc352777fa6e27ad1e11d11ea55651ba93236b\perfmark-api-0.19.0.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.8.6\9180733b7df8542621dc12e21e87557e8c99b8cb\gson-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\Cast\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.android\annotations\4.1.1.4\a1678ba907bf92691d879fef34e1a187038f9259\annotations-4.1.1.4.jar com.tolearn.ApplicationKt
13:56:09.732 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.grpc.server.GrpcEmbeddedServer]

Message: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
Path Taken: new GrpcEmbeddedServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,GrpcServerConfiguration grpcServerConfiguration,[ServerBuilder serverBuilder],ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,ComputeInstanceMetadataResolver computeInstanceMetadataResolver,List metadataContributors)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.grpc.server.GrpcEmbeddedServer]

Message: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
Path Taken: new GrpcEmbeddedServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,GrpcServerConfiguration grpcServerConfiguration,[ServerBuilder serverBuilder],ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,ComputeInstanceMetadataResolver computeInstanceMetadataResolver,List metadataContributors)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1925)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2679)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2665)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2337)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2311)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1245)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1013)
    at io.micronaut.grpc.server.$GrpcEmbeddedServerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1898)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2679)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2665)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2337)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2311)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1266)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:744)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:149)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:66)
    at com.tolearn.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at com.tolearn.endpoint.DemoMoneyServiceGrpcKt$DemoMoneyServiceCoroutineImplBase$bindService$1.<init>(DemoMoneyGrpcKt.kt)
    at com.tolearn.endpoint.DemoMoneyServiceGrpcKt$DemoMoneyServiceCoroutineImplBase.bindService(DemoMoneyGrpcKt.kt:90)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.addService(AbstractServerImplBuilder.java:120)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.addService(AbstractServerImplBuilder.java:56)
    at io.micronaut.grpc.server.GrpcServerBuilder.serverBuilder(GrpcServerBuilder.java:58)
    at io.micronaut.grpc.server.$GrpcServerBuilder$ServerBuilder0Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1898)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Logs when I try to gradle run from command line

```
C:\_d\toLearn\demo-money>gradle run

> Task :run FAILED
14:43:44.395 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.grpc.server.GrpcEmbeddedServer]

Message: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
Path Taken: new GrpcEmbeddedServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,GrpcServerConfiguration grpcServerConfiguration,[ServerBuilder serverBuilder],ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,ComputeInstanceMetadataResolver computeInstanceMetadataResolver,List metadataContributors)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.grpc.server.GrpcEmbeddedServer]

Message: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
Path Taken: new GrpcEmbeddedServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,GrpcServerConfiguration grpcServerConfiguration,[ServerBuilder serverBuilder],ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,ComputeInstanceMetadataResolver computeInstanceMetadataResolver,List metadataContributors)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1925)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2679)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2665)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2337)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2311)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1245)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1013)
        at io.micronaut.grpc.server.$GrpcEmbeddedServerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1898)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2679)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2665)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2337)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2311)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1266)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:744)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:149)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:66)
        at com.tolearn.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at com.tolearn.endpoint.DemoMoneyServiceGrpcKt$DemoMoneyServiceCoroutineImplBase$bindService$1.<init>(DemoMoneyGrpcKt.kt)
        at com.tolearn.endpoint.DemoMoneyServiceGrpcKt$DemoMoneyServiceCoroutineImplBase.bindService(DemoMoneyGrpcKt.kt:90)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.addService(AbstractServerImplBuilder.java:120)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.addService(AbstractServerImplBuilder.java:56)
        at io.micronaut.grpc.server.GrpcServerBuilder.serverBuilder(GrpcServerBuilder.java:58)
        at io.micronaut.grpc.server.$GrpcServerBuilder$ServerBuilder0Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1898)
        ... 17 common frames omitted

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\JDKs\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date

C:\_d\toLearn\demo-money>
```

IntelliJ

[image: Kotlin 1.4 and Java11]

I guess it is an issue with version conflicts but I can't imagine what try.

So my straight question is, what can I try in order to fix this issue? Possible solution may be related to the fact I am using kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10. If so, what can I try or maybe downgrade?

It is interesting that I can build successfully the application but I am getting the error mentioned above only when I try execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the Gradle build (thanks for providing the sample project!), there’s a warning that should put you onto the right track:

```
> Task :kaptGenerateStubsKotlin
w: Some JAR files in the classpath have the Kotlin Runtime library bundled into them. This may cause difficult to debug problems if there's a different version of the Kotlin Runtime library in the classpath. Consider removing these libraries from the classpath
w: /home/chriki/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0/d6c8cbe29c60b202165593be5244ce43d37378ac/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-jdk7.jar: Library has Kotlin runtime bundled into it
```

So, the solution is to remove the `protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin` dependency from the `implementation` configuration. In other words, remove the following line from your `dependencies` block:

```
    implementation("io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0:jdk7@jar")
```

The dependency is not needed here, it’s pointing to a plugin artifact which is only needed in the Protobuf compilation. Thus, having it configured under `protobuf.plugins` (as is already the case) should be sufficient.